# JavaScript calculator not working out

Tags: javascript

so I am attempting to make a calculator for my JavaScript class. My professor gave me a zipper file containing the empty JavaScript file, as well as the CSS and other files (so I am not building the actual design of the calculator, just adding the functions in the JS file so that it can add, subtract, multiply, and divide).

Everything works fine except for one thing: my professor said that, if either of the two numbers (it can only take two at a time) entered into the calculator is null or not a number, the calculator should not output anything, it should just be blank where the answer box is. However, no matter how much I tweak the code, I cannot get it to do this. I have tried everything I could think of, but it is still showing stuff in the answer box when one of the two number boxes is empty (it displays NaN in the answer box if I enter a letter or something - but it should be blank). Please help.

This is my code:

```
var operand1 = document.getElementById("operand1");
var operand2 = document.getElementById("operand2");
var answer = document.getElementById("answer"); 

function tester(num1, num2) {
    if (num1 || num2 == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function getOperation(operation) {
  if (operation === "add" && tester(operand1.value, operand2.value) == true) {
    return function (){
        answer.value = Number(operand1.value) + Number(operand2.value);
    } 
  }
  if (operation === "subtract" && tester(operand1.value, operand2.value) == true) {
    return function (){
        answer.value = Number(operand1.value) - Number(operand2.value);
    }
  }
  if (operation === "multiply" && tester(operand1.value, operand2.value) == true) {
    return function (){
        answer.value = Number(operand1.value) * Number(operand2.value);
    }
  }
  if (operation === "divide" && tester(operand1.value, operand2.value) == true) {
    return function (){
        answer.value = Number(operand1.value) / Number(operand2.value);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = getOperation("add");
document.getElementById("subtract").onclick = getOperation("subtract");
document.getElementById("multiply").onclick = getOperation("multiply");
document.getElementById("divide").onclick = getOperation("divide");
```

Comment: `if (num1 || num2 == null) {` should be `if (num1 == null || num2 == null) {`

Comment: i didn't see your code handled the case when tester(a,b) is false. in fact if you adding if(tester(a,b)==false) answer.value="" in the getOperation(), it may solve the problem

Comment: Yes that is the problem. || operation is for binary operands. When you do not type both 0 as operands it never returns 0. If it ever  returns 0 it is not == null . So try `if (num1 == null || num2 == null) {`

Comment: your first if condition must be `if (!num1.trim() || !num2.trim()) {` which means this will be true if num1 or num2 is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code

1. `(num1 || num2 == null` checks whether `num1` is truthy and `num2` is not null, you need to check whether `num1` and `num2` has any content
2. The test should happen in event call, so it should go to the event handling method

So

```js
var operand1 = document.getElementById("operand1");
var operand2 = document.getElementById("operand2");
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");

function tester(num1, num2) {
  num1 = num1.trim();
  num2 = num2.trim();
  return num1 && num2 && !isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2);
}

function getOperation(operator) {
  return function() {
    if (tester(operand1.value, operand2.value)) {
      answer.value = operator(Number(operand1.value), Number(operand2.value));
    } else {
      answer.value = '';
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = getOperation(function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
});
document.getElementById("subtract").onclick = getOperation(function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 - num2;
});
document.getElementById("multiply").onclick = getOperation(function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 * num2;
});
document.getElementById("divide").onclick = getOperation(function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 / num2;
});
```

```html
<input id="operand1" />
<input id="operand2" />
<br />
<input id="answer" readonly />
<br />
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
<input type="button" id="subtract" value="Subtract" />
<input type="button" id="multiply" value="multiply" />
<input type="button" id="divide" value="Divide" />
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant thank you! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

To check for null, do the following:

```
 if (num1 === null || num2 === null)
```

Your condition (num1 || num2 == null) will check if the boolean variable that is the result of num1 || num2 is equal to null or not.